# Add author specific social links to Squarespace blog post

Tags: html, json, squarespace

Working with Squarespace. At the bottom of each blog post I'm trying to get the authors name, bio, avatar, and applicable social media links to show.

I've solved with the exception of the Twitter and Facebook links.

Anyone know the variable to include these?

Here's my working code:

```
        {.section author}

          <span class="author-name">

            {.if author.avatarId}

            <div class="bespoke-avatar">

               <a href="{collection.fullUrl}?author={author.id}">

                <img src="/global/{author.avatarId}?format=36w" />

              </a>

            </div>

            {.end}

            <div class="bespoke-info">

              <em class="bespoke-author-name">{displayName}</em>

              <em>{author.bio}</em>

            </div>

          </span>

        {.end}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a json object that is storing the social links.

`authenticatedAccount -> socialOptions`

```
"socialOptions" : [ {
  "type" : "facebook",
  "username" : "http://facebook.com"
}, {
  "type" : "twitter",
  "username" : "http://twitter.com"
}, {
  "type" : "google",
  "username" : "https://plus.google.com/"
} ],
```

Go to your main site add `?format=json-pretty` and look for the above object.